# May someone let me know what kind of license I need?

Tags: rest-api, licenses, community, connected-apps, canvas

I was wondering if someone may help me in terms of Salesforce license, I am really puzzle due to there are lot of docs about that even I've talked to sales departament and I think it was worst.

Thing is I just need a license to develop a canvas and have a connected app in my salesforce account in order to connect my website with salesforce. Nowdays we just need to use **Oauth** and **Canvas** in Salesforce so I have been reasearching about those topics and I think I have to purchase a light force.com account which is 10$/month [pricing-platform](http://www.salesforce.com/crm/editions-pricing-platform.jsp) . That's actually good nevertheless I am afraid that we need to buy an administrator license to manage to use that connected app, is that true? I mean may someone let me know if we need to buy 2 kind of licenses, adminsitrator license and light force.com account.

Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Didilin I don't think I can fully answer your question but I can give you some possibly useful info: 1. Force.com license will give you access to the platform just like a Salesforce license BUT NOT access to the standard objects such as Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities. You have to build all your objects from scratch. 2. You can be have an admin license for the same price as the rest. 3. There are different tiers of Force.com licenses offering different functionality. 4. You will have to consider the license/edition requirements too of the app at this stage.

Comment: I think I just need a developer edition to get my aims because I want to create a canvas in order to publish it in the appexchange as well as let my users connect through chatter using OAuth2.Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reading between the lines, it appears you have a Salesforce production instance with some existing users, correct? You don't need a separate user account to show them a canvas app through a publisher action, visualforce page, etc.

To create a canvas app, you need to spin up a free Developer Edition org at http://developer.force.com/ and package your app there. The development and management of your app takes place in this free DE org.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/canvas_framework.pdf

Comment: Thanks greenstork. Honestly I just need to get a connected app in order to create a canvas app and get Oauth setting to let my users use their chatter account to access to my web site. I don't need anything else. Do you thing a developer account will be enough?. Cheers

Comment: You'll need a DE org to package up a connected app, yes.